# Convert Audio 5.1 to Stereo

Tags: audio, video, conversion, stereo, ac3

I am having issues playing the MKV video files I download on my friends TV, the TV shows I download have been playing just fine with no issues.  The video portion of the files play flawlessly however the audio is another story.  I believe the issue is because the movie files have 5.1 DTS audio, while the TV shows have AC3 stereo audio.

Could someone recommend a program, preferably freeware, that can down mix and convert the audio from 5.1 DTS to AC3 stereo?

Comment: We don't deal with software recommendations here; they tend to go out out of date quickly and attract spam. You might be able to get help at softwarerecs.stackexchange.com (after reading their documentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find what I was looking for, here is how I did it.

To convert the audio part of the mkv file I used - [Pazera Free Audio Extractor](http://www.pazera-software.com/products/audio-extractor/) - You could also use [TFM Audio Tool](http://tfm-audio-tool.software.informer.com/)

After you have converted the audio file you can recombine the audio file and video file with [MKVToolNix](https://mkvtoolnix.download/) - be sure to deselect the audio track that is already in the mkv file, or set the new audio track to default, before muxing it all together.